# Visual C++ 6.0 WholeArchive

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-6, ghidra

I'm reverse engineering an old computer program compiled using Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0. I'd like to let Ghidra recognize all the functions from the CRT library which is statically linked.

I've tried compiling a simple program that uses fopen and giving it to Ghidra's Function ID, and it successfully recognized fopen in the original executable. Now I want it to recognize more functions but I don't want to write all of them in my program.

Is there a way to force MSVC++ 6.0 to include all statically linked symbols? (Something like /WHOLEARCHIVE in Visual Studio 2015+)

Comment: Don't know of an automated way to do it, but maybe `dumpbin /symbols` to get the public symbols and `link /include` to force them in.

Comment: if manually giving Function ID for one function worked, maybe it could be scripted in ghidra?